# Finding installed programs in linux in a c++ program

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing a program that opens an application on giving the name of the application to the program as input. How do I make the program search for the application at run time and find out whether it is installed or not in a linux system? I am writing the program in c++.

Comment: Hint: you can use unix command _which_ to find out full path of executable

Comment: You could also examine the `PATH` environment variable. That's how a shell locates an executable when you type a command.

Comment: It is easy to use `sudo apt-get `

Comment: Do you mean installed as in installed from a package using apt-get or pkg or do you mean the executable exists but has not necessarily been installed (it could come as default with the OS) or do you mean when you type in the command, you want to know which one it is picking up (possibly because there are several versions).

Comment: Refer same question asked here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/how-do-i-list-all-installed-programs

Comment: @user3184706: That's much less portable than just examining what's in `PATH` with `which`.

Comment: unix command which is showing the path of the executable to the standard output but it returns an integer 0 ,1 or 2 right ? But all I want is to take that path and then run the executable using that path with the system() command. How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that by installed programs you mean programs that are in `PATH` directory, then do:

```
if (system("which programName") != 0)
    //your program is not installed in PATH directory
```